# Go back a folder in php

Tags: php, html

i know my question seems a bit vague but an example will do wonders.
For example :
When you go into a folder you use : `<?php include_once 'includes/header.inc.php' ?>`
when you want to go back one you use ../../ to go back you get the idea. However is there by chance a better way of doing this cuz i've found it's easy to break?

vague but i hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

I've obviously tried the ../ to go back to parent directory or folder. When i google i tend to find how to go back using header etc but i dont think that'll help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` as the starting point for all your `includes` and `requires`...  That way it will be portable between dev and production as well.

Here you can read about [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

IE

```
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/public/foo/bar/includes/header.inc.php';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate the help. It was simple but helped me out a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than basing everything off of the document root, which is not necessarily the root of your actual project, nor is it populated outside of an HTTP context, I generally do the following.

In a config file for which you *definitely* know the location relative to your application's root:

```php
define('APP_ROOT', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../path/to/dir'));
// will result in something like: /var/www/somesite/path/to/dir
```

and, for good measure:

```php
define('WEB_ROOT', 'https://example.com/my/app/');
```